# Kendo UI Hierarchy grid and master grid refresh loop after edit

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I am having one strange issue, I have Kendo UI Grid and Hierarchy Grid , both are editable with batch true.
The issue is when i edit detail grid the master and detail grid refresh, and if i edit one more time both refreshes twice and the next time it refresh 3 times.There is some kind of loop going on which i am not able to figure out. Below is the jsfiddle url:

```js
var data = {
"Conditions": [
{
"ConditionId": 1651239,
"Priority": 10,
"Description": " ARRIVAL TIME IN 12:12 | DAY OF WEEK IN 3 | DEPARTURE AIRPORT = IAD",
"OperationCode": {
"Disabled": false,
"Group": null,
"Selected": false,
"Text": "Add",
"Value": "A"
},
"Contents": [
{
"Id": 114605,
"ConditionId": 1651239,
"QtyCalculationType": 3,
"FixedLoadQty": null,
"NperPax": null,
"MperPax": null,
"LoadPercentage": 20,
"Portion": 1,
"RoundMethod": {
"Disabled": false,
"Group": null,
"Selected": false,
"Text": "S - Standard Rounding",
"Value": "S"
},
"MinQty": null,
"MaxQty": null,
"Factor": 2,
"LoadRatio": {
"Id": 364,
"Code": "1/80"
},
"PaxFigCalc": {
"Disabled": false,
"Group": null,
"Selected": false,
"Text": "",
"Value": "0"
},
"PaxFactor": null,
"RotationPlanCode": null,
"RotationPlanNumber": null
},
{
"Id": 155296,
"ConditionId": 1651239,
"QtyCalculationType": 0,
"FixedLoadQty": null,
"NperPax": null,
"MperPax": null,
"LoadPercentage": null,
"Portion": 0,
"RoundMethod": {
"Disabled": false,
"Group": null,
"Selected": false,
"Text": "",
"Value": " "
},
"MinQty": null,
"MaxQty": null,
"Factor": 0,
"LoadRatio": {
"Id": 0,
"Code": ""
},
"PaxFigCalc": {
"Disabled": false,
"Group": null,
"Selected": false,
"Text": "",
"Value": "0"
},
"PaxFactor": null,
"RotationPlanCode": null,
"RotationPlanNumber": null
}
]
}
]
};
  
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  editable: true,
  pageable:false,
  scrollable:true,
  height: 450,
  sortable:true,
  columns: [
            { field: "Priority", title: "Pri", attributes: { "class": "tc editable-cell" }, width: "50px"},
            { field: "OperationCode", title: "Operations",attributes: { "class": "tc" }, width:"100px", template:"#=OperationCode.Text#" },
            { field: "Description", title: "Description",attributes: { "class": "desc" } },
          
        ],
  dataSource: {
    batch: true,
    data : data.Conditions,
    schema : {
      model : {
        id : "ConditionId",
        fields : {
          ConditionId: { editable: false, nullable: true },
          OperationCode: { editable: false },
          Description: { editable: false },
          Priority: {
            validation: {
              required: true,
              prioValidation: function (input) {
                if (input.is("[name='Priority']")) {
                  input.attr("data-prioValidation-msg", "Enter a number");
                  return /^[0-9]/.test(input.val());
                }
                return true;
              }
            },
            type: "number"
          }
        }
      }
    }
        
  },
  detailInit : detailGrid,
  dataBound : gridReady
});
 function gridReady(e){
  this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));
    console.log("Master Grid refreshed.")
  }
  function detailGrid(e) {
    
            e.detailRow.find(".k-hierarchy-cell").addClass("c"+e.data.ConditionId);
            $("<div class='"+e.data.uid+"' />").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data :  e.data.Contents,
                    batch: true,
                    schema: {
                        model : {
                            id : "Id",
                            fields: {
                                FixedLoadQty: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                NperPax: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                MperPax: { type: "number" , nullable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                                Portion: { type: "number" , nullable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                                RoundMethod: {  nullable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                                MinQty: { type: "number" , nullable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                                MaxQty: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                Factor: { nullable: true, validation: { required: false } },
                                LoadPercentage: { nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                LoadRatio: { nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                PaxFigCalc: { nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                PaxFactor: { nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                RotationPlanCode: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false }  },
                                RotationPlanNumber: { type: "number", nullable: true, validation: { required: false } }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: false,
                pageable: false,
                editable: true,
                navigatable: true,
                columns: [
                   
                    { field: "FixedLoadQty", title:"Fixed Qty", width : 80, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "NperPax", title:"Nper", width : 50,  attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" } },
                    { field: "MperPax", title:"Mpax", width : 50,  attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "Portion", title:"Prtn", width : 50,  attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "RoundMethod", title:"Rounding", width : 90, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }, template:"#=RoundMethod.Text#"  },
                    { field: "MinQty", title:"Min", width : 50, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "MaxQty", title:"Max", width : 50, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "Factor", title:"Factor", width : 80, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "LoadPercentage", title:"Load %", width : 80, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "LoadRatio", title:"Load Ratio", width : 100, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }, template:"#=LoadRatio.Code#"  },
                    { field: "PaxFigCalc", title:"Pax Fig", width : 80, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }, template:"#=PaxFigCalc.Text#" },
                    { field: "PaxFactor", title:"Pax Factor", width : 90, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  },
                    { field: "RotationPlanCode", title:"Rotation Type", width : 120, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" } },
                    { field: "RotationPlanNumber", title:"Rotation No", width : 100, attributes: { "class": "editable-cell" }  }
                ],
                save: function(e) {
                  //  $("#QtyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.get(e.model.ConditionId).dirty = true;
                  //  chkFields(e);
                },
                dataBound: gridReadyDetail
            });

            function test (c,o){
                debugger
            }
            function gridReadyDetail (e) {
              console.log("Detail Grid refreshed.")
                var grid = this;
                $(".delQtyContent").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); //get the row for deletion
                    var data = grid.dataItem(tr);

                    $("#removeAlert .removeHeader").html("Confirm Content Removal");
                    $("#removeAlert .alertText").html("You have chosen to delete the quantity content. Do you wish to proceed?");
                    common.gridPopUp("open", "#removeAlert", window.gg.sacs.resources.Attention, "508px", true);
                    $("#removeAlert .action-continue").off().on("click", function (a) {
                        a.preventDefault();
                        if (data.id == 0) {
                            grid.dataSource.remove(data);
                            grid.dataSource["_destroyed"] = []
                        } else {
                            callAjax(baseUrl + "Operations/CateringRule/DeleteQtyContent?qtyContentId=" + data.Id + "&ruleId="+self.CRViewmodel.Id(), "POST")
                                .done(function (res) {
                                    grid.dataSource.remove(data);
                                    grid.dataSource["_destroyed"] = [] // cheat for kendo to clear the destroy function
                                });
                        }
                        common.gridPopUp("close", "#removeAlert");
                        toastr.success("Content has been removed.");
                    });
                    $("#noButton").click(function () {
                        common.gridPopUp("close", "#removeAlert");
                    })
                })
                applyValidations (this);
                if (this.dataSource.data().length <2 ) {
                    this.tbody.find(".delQtyContent").remove();
                }
            }

            function applyValidations (grid) {
               /* var data = grid.dataSource.at(0);
                data.fields["MaxQty"].editable = false;*/


               // var row = e.sender.tbody.find("[data-uid='" + dataItems[j].uid + "']"); // row
                //var cell = row.children().eq(columnIndex); // cell
            }

            function chkFields(e) {
                if (e.values.hasOwnProperty("FixedLoadQty") && e.values.FixedLoadQty != null) {
                    disableFields (group1,e)
                }
            }

            function disableFields (grp,grid) {2
                var row = grid.sender.tbody.find("[data-uid='" + grid.model.uid + "']");

                $(grp).each(function (i,val) {
                    var columnIndex = grid.sender.wrapper.find(".k-grid-header [data-field=" + val + "]").index();
                    var cell = row.children().eq(columnIndex);
                    cell.removeClass("editable-cell");
                    //var data = grid.sender.dataSource.at(0);
                    //data.fields[val].editable = false
                })
            }

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.221/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/euLmnmne/3/
Any Help would be highly appreciated.